# Conversão de dados factor para numeric

Tags: r

No seguinte exemplo:

```
> str(rhm)
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ plant     : Factor w/ 1 level "LaR": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ time      : int  0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 7 7 ...
 $ Tratamento: Factor w/ 4 levels "T1pH1","T1pH2",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ wt        : Factor w/ 20 levels "0,0013","0,0017",..: 20 20 20 20 10 16 18 17 12 19 ...
> str(unclass(rhm$wt))
 atomic [1:24] 20 20 20 20 10 16 18 17 12 19 ...
 - attr(*, "levels")= chr [1:20] "0,0013" "0,0017" "0,0036" "0,0045" ...
```

Ao tentar transformar a variável wt em número, ao invés de "0,0013", "0.0017"... aparecem:

```
as.numeric(rhm$wt)
[1:24] 20 20 20 20 10 16 18 17 12 19 ...
```

Como converter wt para números?

Tentei duas formas sugeridas em fórum:

```
as.numeric(as.character(rhm$wt))
as.numeric(levels(rhm$wt))[rhm$wt]
```

Contudo ocorre a substituição dos meus dados por NAs:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Como posso transformar meus dados corretamente?

Answer (score 4):

No `R` o separador de casas decimais é `.`. 
Para o seu código funcionar você tem duas opções:

Usar o seguinte código para converter `factor` em numérico:

```
as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", as.character(rhm$wt)))
```

A função `gsub` com esses argumentos troca todas as vírgulas por ponto. Em seguida o R consegue converter de `chr` para `numeric`. Veja esse exemplo simples:

```
> as.numeric("0,1")
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", "0,1"))
[1] 0.1
```

Outra forma é: na leitura dos dados, que você provavelmente está usando o `read.table`. Usar o argumento `sep = ","` indicando que o seu separador de casas decimais é `,`.

Comment: Só lembrando que a opção 2, de corrigir na leitura dos dados, é bem mais interessante pois resolve o problema para todas colunas de uma vez (se for o caso) e usa menos caracteres.

Comment: Obrigada! Resolvido!